# Getting content of an element as string with unescaped HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, dom-node

I'm using `xmldom` parser from npm library, it's based on the DOMNode object model. Having the following code:

```
var xml = "<p>Test</p><toFetch id="1">test\n\n<p>aaa</p>test\n</toFetch>";
var parser = new dom.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
```

I want to get the content of the `toFetch` tag, as a string with all unescaped HTML tags inside, and without the `toFetch` tag itself.

What I have is:

```
var elements = parser.getElementsByTagName("toFetch");
elements.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.toString());
});
```

It works, but it gives me the string with `toFetch` surrounding tag. How can I get only the content?

Comment: xml.split("<to Fetch")[1].split("</toFetch>")[0]

Answer (score 1):

Your string has a typo in it. The `1` should be in single quotes, not doubles.

Then, change: `console.log(element.toString());`

To: `console.log(element.textContent);`

Comment: It gives me only the first child, without inner tags

Comment: @user99999 Updated answer.

Comment: Tried this as well, it strips all HTML tags, I don't want that.

Comment: @user99999 Not sure about this with XML, but have you tried: `element.innerHTML`?

Comment: Yup, this would be ideal, but XML does not have this property.

Comment: @user99999 Ok, how about: `element.firstChild.toString();`

Comment: Nope, same thing. It gives me just the first child.